# How do I get keyboard inputs from the user using C and linux?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

I have to make a short program that, creates two child processes, each one accepting an integer from the keyboard and writes them to a pipe, from where the parent process summarizes them and displays the total on the screen.

I've written one with scanf(), but it freezes up and it doesn't give me the sum.  How do I make it work with scanf or any other way if possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int pipe(int pd[2]);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int pd[2], sum=0, num=0;
    if(pipe(pd) == -1)
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            scanf("%d", num);
            if(write(pd[1], &num, sizeof(int)) == -1)
                printf("Error: Write()");           
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        wait(NULL);
        if(read(pd[0], &num, sizeof(int)) == -1)
            printf("Error: Read()");

        sum += num;
    }
    printf("Total: %d\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: You need some synchronization between your processes to ensure they aren't both trying to read from the terminal at the same time; otherwise AFAIK you can't be sure which one will get the data.  Also note that the child processes will continue to run past the `if(fork()==0)` block, so you probably want to put an `_exit()` at the end of that block.

Comment: Are you hitting Enter after typing in the number?

Comment: @NateEldredge Can you help implement synchronization? I know that I need a semaphore or mutex but I don't know how to distinguish between two children when they're running the code.  And I will put the _exit() command at the end of the code as well.

Comment: @Joseph SIble-Reinstate Monica Yes I am, but it just goes to a new line.

Comment: Since the children both do the same thing, you don't need to distinguish between them.  They can both try to lock the semaphore; one will succeed and the other will wait until the first one unlocks it.

Comment: Sweet, I'll give that a try @NateEldredge

Comment: @NateEldredge Also do you know a way to make scanf work or a different way to get an integer from the keyboard with linux using C?

Comment: @NateEldredge As it turns out, the line buffering that TTY's do means that in practice, each child will get one complete line of input without having to do any locking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of problems here:

- You have `if(pipe(pd) == -1)`, and I assume you meant to have an error handler as the "then" clause for it, but you don't, so children will only spawn if the pipe fails, which is basically the opposite of what you want.
- You have `scanf("%d", num);`. You need `&num` since `num` isn't already a pointer.
- You need to `return` or `exit` from the child processes, or they'll fall into the next loop and consume the output.

With just those things fixed, it's enough to make it work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int pipe(int pd[2]);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int pd[2], sum=0, num=0;
    if(pipe(pd) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            scanf("%d", &num);
            if(write(pd[1], &num, sizeof(int)) == -1)
                printf("Error: Write()");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        wait(NULL);
        if(read(pd[0], &num, sizeof(int)) == -1)
            printf("Error: Read()");

        sum += num;
    }
    printf("Total: %d\n", sum);
}
```

There's a few other things you should fix too, but they're not complete show-stoppers. Here's what jumped out at me:

- You don't need to declare your own `pipe` prototype. The one from unistd.h is fine.
- You should handle the case where `fork` or `scanf` fail.
- You should handle partial reads and writes.
- You should close the read end of the pipe in the children and the write end of the pipe in the parent after forking.
- You should consider using a lock to control reading input, so that it doesn't depend on TTY line buffering to work reliably.